# Why is my image not showing up?

Tags: html, css, image, nivo-slider

Before I put this code in:

```
<div id="bannerInRight"> <img src="images/race.jpg" width="475" height="258"/></div>
```

I had a "nivo slider" in its place.  I tried to delete all the nivo code I could find, but now the image isn't appearing at all.

Below is my CSS:

```
#bannerInRight {
float: right;
height: 261px;
margin: 8px 28px 20px;
width: 475px;
}
```

And here is the live link if that helps at all: http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm6.php

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to add the right image path

Comment: The image path is fine; the image is hidden by CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stylenew.css` file includes:

```
#bannerInRight img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

which causes the image to remain hidden.

Remove this rule and the image shows up.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  Don't know why that was even in the CSS, thanks.